# Passing an array to a function, but if it doesn't return true I want to pass an extra digit?

Tags: c++

So for my code I want to pass an argument to a function and if it doesn't return true, I want it to pass the next index digit in the int array.

So if areaIntA[0] = 0; doesn't return true, I want it to pass areaIntA[0][1] = 01; and if that doesn't return true, areaIntA[0][1][2] = 012; etc...

My updated code:

```
areaInt = areaIntA[0];

do {
    areaCheck = isRegistered(file, areaInt);
    if (areaCheck != 1)
    {
    areaInt = areaIntA[i] * 10 + areaIntA[i+1];
    i++;
    }
} while (areaCheck != 1);

cout << areaCheck << endl;
```

This compiles but it shows a segmentation error, anyone know why?

Comment: Are you working with integers or strings?  What is the type of `areaInt`?

Comment: I am working with integers, it is an int

Answer (score 0):

Have the function take in a list (vector). for every call add a new element to the end.

eg.

```
List< int?> areaIntList;

do {
    areaIntList.Add(areaInt[i]);
    areaCheck = isRegistered(file, areaInt[i]);
    if (areaCheck != 1)
    {
        i++;
    }
} while (areaCheck != 1);
```

isRegistered takes in a List of your used type.

Comment: int? cause i dont knwo what type areaInt[] is

Answer (score 0):

You're weirdly equating array integer values in a sort of string context.  That usually means base-10 math.

Try:

```
int val = 0;
do {
    val = 10 * val + areaInt[i];
    areaCheck = isRegistered(file, val);
    if (areaCheck != 1)
        i++;
} while (areaCheck != 1);
```

On the first pass, `val` will be the value of `areaInt[0]`;  On the second pass, it will be `areaInt[0]` followed by `areaInt[1]` (e.g. 0 and 1 become 1, 1 and 2 become 12).  And so on.

Comment: I wouldn't want 0 and 1 to become 1, I would want 0 and 1 to become 01.

Comment: also 1 and 2 becoming 12 wouldn't be the same as areaInt[0] = 1 areaInt[1] = 2, it would be just like areaInt[0] = 12.

Comment: Hi so I used a variation of the code you gave me, I updated my original post could you take a look and maybe see what is wrong with it?

Comment: You probably need to check your array bounds to prevent the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is this:

1. `isRegistered` is a function that takes a file and a variable-length string of digits, returning `1` if the string is registered and `0` otherwise.
2. `areaInt` is a C-style string like `"31526"`.
3. What you want is to see if `"3"` is registered; if not, see if `"31"` is registered; if not, try `"315"`, etc until all the digits of `areaInt` are exhausted.
4. The end result should be a substring of `areaInt` which is the shortest registered string, or an error if no registered string was found.

This is how I'd do it.

> 1. If the input string `areaInt` is empty, return an error.
> 2. Loop a counter `i` from 1 to the length of the string:
>
>    1. Construct a test string `s` from the first `i` characters in `areaInt`.
>    2. Test if `s` is registered.  If it is, break out of the loop and return `s`.  If not, continue the loop.
> 3. If the loop completes at the end of `areaInt` and no registered string has been found, return an error.

**Note.** Make sure you stop at the end of `areaInt`.  Otherwise if you get to the end of `areaInt` and still haven't found a string that is registered, then you will overrun the buffer and try to read an element not in the string.

Comment: Yes you described it how I want the code to work, except that areaInt is an INT not a string, and it is passing to the function as an int.

Comment: @user1895783 There's no way you can pass a single `int` "01" to a function and have it recognise that it should be interpreted as two digits instead of a single digit "1".  I think you need to change the signature of `isRegistered` either to take an additional argument for the length (so that it can pad with zeros when necessary), or to take a string input so that leading zeros can be passed in.

Comment: So I realized that it doesn't have to take more than 1 index from an array, just needs to pass 1 int value. I'll edit my code in a sec to show the updated version, but it compiles but it gets a segmentation error! Maybe you can see whats wrong?